# sqlite integer value seems to be too high

Tags: c++, sqlite

i have a sqlite table

```
"CREATE TABLE [hash_tab] ("
"[hash]  INTEGER  UNIQUE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"
"[expression] VARCHAR(200),"
 "[inserted] VARCHAR(25))
```

and a command which inserts a new record:

```
insert into hash_tab (hash,expression,inserted) values(6624471614268135350,"value",strftime('Y-m-1912818479 H:M:0.000000', 'now'))
```

The command does not fail but when i check the database, hash value is 0.
The hash value should get converted to 8 byte integer which max is:

```
9223372036854775807
```

This value is higher than

```
6624471614268135350
```

When i cut the number in the upper command, the value for column hash is set correctly.

```
 insert into hash_tab (hash,expression,inserted) values(6624471614,"value",strftime('Y-m-1912818479 H:M:0.000000', 'now'))
```

I use one of the latest amalgamation. I need those high numbers for a higher hash space. How to accomplish this. Thank you

Comment: Works for me (once I've corrected the wrong table name). Show your code.

Comment: What's `commands2`, and how, if at all, is it related to `hash_tab`?

Comment: Sorry, please replace commands2 by hash_tab. (I copied from production code and for simpliciation i changed names).

Comment: Ok, it works not for me. What could be the reason? I get no error, just a row inserted with hash=0.

Comment: To edit the question, click "edit". And you are still keeping your C++ code secret.

Comment: I checked it out with SQLiteAdmin. 2147483647 (INT_MAX) is the limit. 2147483648 leads to zero inserted into column hash, at least on my DEBUG 64 build.

Comment: CREATE TABLE [test] (
[int64] INTEGER  NULL
)

insert into test (int64) values(6624471614268135350)
SELECT * from test

This returns 0. SQLITE definitely does handle 64 bit integer

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, SQLite works correctly here.

I used SQLiteAdministrator to inspect the table. SQLiteAdministrator is a 32 bit application. Obviously it is not able to process 64 bit integers.